# Does everything go inside a class?

Tags: c++, oop

I have another rudimentary question. I somewhat recall hearing that everything in C++ goes inside a class. Then I hear that classes shouldn't be used where possible. So my question goes: When do you make classes and when do you not? (an example or two would be cool)

And a random side-question: When is it appropriate to put 2 classes in one header? Or does it matter?

Comment: You should really base your learning on something more substantial than overheard conversations.

Comment: An example of something not in a class would be the math functions in C++.

Comment: Being forced to put everything in a class is how you end up being forced to "invent" the "design pattern" called the Singleton.

Comment: @Christian That's not how Java does it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ everything need not go inside a class(as opposed to Java where everything does go inside a class).

1. You should make a class when you want to represent some real world entity for example a person, a customer, an user, animal, car etc. You require to store some data about the entity and have some functions related to the entity.

   For Example: Customer. You create a customer class. Customer has the following data to be stored. {name,age,address,phone}. You need some functions like addCustomer(), sendMessage() etc.
2. Choice of where to use classes and where not to is a serious design issue. There is no general rule. Before you begin your application, you need to sit down with a paper and pencil and brainstorm the basic classes you will be requiring. You can always add and fine tune your design in the future. While designing your classes the most important thing to be kept in mind is code re-usability. Also try to keep your code as loosely coupled as possible.
3. As a standard practice, you should have one class per header file.

Answer (score 11):

> Does everything go inside a class?

No, most definitly not. Classes are part of Object Oriented Programming, but C++ isn't just that, in contrast to, say, Java or C#.

C++ is a *multi-paradigm* language, which means that it also allows other stuff. That's because the biggest drawback when using OOP is *reusability of algorithms*.
Sure, you can just write certain functions for every class out there, but how cool would it be to just write it once and be done with it forever? That's what STL is build on. Classes in the STL, like `vector`, only have the member functions they *absolutly need* for encapsulation. Most of them are unique anyways, like how you retrieve the first element from a `vector` is different from retrieving the first element of a `list`. All that is encapsulated and abstracted away by member functions like `front` and `back` (for direct access to the members), or `begin` and `end` (for iterator-access).

Now, all other algorithmic stuff is a free function as long as it works on more than one class and doesn't need direct access to the internals of that class. Take `std::sort` as an example. It works on any iterator-pair as long as they are random access iterators. In the STL, that would be `vector` and `deque`, with C++0x we get `array`, but outside of the STL, ***your classes too*** if they provide such iterators. Or even more prominent, C style arrays! Yes, you can use them for sort, very easily:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  int arr[5] = { 5, 2, 4, 1, 3 };
  std::sort(&arr[0], &arr[0] + 5);
  // arr == { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
}
```

Write once, use everywhere.

As a last point, [this article by Scott Meyers](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184401197) is a very very interesting read on class design and when to use free functions and when not.

Comment: Congrats for reaching 10k. :)

Comment: +1 The STL is such a beautiful gem.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ it's not necessary to encapsulate everything in a class. C++ is a multi-paradigm programming language, which means that you can either take an object-oriented approach, or procedural (no classes), or some mix of inbetween.

Generally though, encapsulation is a good thing and can improve code readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

Very generally, If something can be called an object, it can be a class. A class should correspond only to a single "real-life" object. Not more than one object and usually not part of an object.
Examples - A Person, a Brush, a Book, a Library, an Application, a Process, a Thread, an Internet connection, a GUI Button, a GUI window.

The option of two classes in one header is up to the coding standards you're working with or those that are enforced why whomever you're writing the code for. Some people would have none of it. Usually it is appropriate when the two classes are quite small and highly related, for instance, inherit from the same base class or interface.

Please consider reading a proper Object oriented and C++ book.

Answer (score 0):

[Classes](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) are part of a programming paradigm called "[Object Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)".

`Person` is a `class`:

```
class Person {
public:
    int age;
}
```

Now we make a few "objects":

```
Person Alice;
Person Bob;
Person Charlie;
```

Now watch:

```
Alice.age = 5;
std::cout << "Alice's age: " << Alice.age << "\n";

Bob.age = 10 * Alice.age;
std::cout << "Bob's age: " << Bob.age << "\n";
```

Output:

```
Alice's age: 5
Bob's age: 50
```

As you can see, `class`es (or `struct`s) can be used to group things together - this allows you to create "anologies".

Comment: Thanks. I understand how they are used, I'm just not sure if everything in your program should belong to a class or not.

Comment: Not really.  The above code would be pretty much the same in C, which is not object-oriented.

Comment: you have very strange naming conventions. typcially ALL_CAPS are reserved for constants, Capitalized for classes, and lowercase for instances/variables.

Comment: @shoosh: That's unjustified, coding conventions are a personal thing, nothing that should be punished on SO. In a team, sure, abide by the coding convention everyone agreed on, but on SO? Come on..

Comment: @Mark That was accidental; I was thinking about Microsoft [`RECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162897(v=vs.85).aspx) style structs.

Answer (score 0):

A class is basically a representation of an object.
The class will hold information about that object and usually methods to change that data.

Everything not in a class in C++ is known as `static` code meaning the method does not require a context to be called on.

Methods in classes (methods in classes can be static as well but let's forget about that for now) require an object to call them on.

If you have a static method `foo(int, int)` and a class method `bar(int, int)` in the class `Example`

boo is called like this:

`foo(3, 4);`

while bar would be called like this:

```
Example obj;
obj.bar(3, 4);
```

Object oriented programming (with classes) have several advantages and most of the commonly used languages today are OOP.